# align labels with textarea

Tags: html, css

[image]

I've some textareas and text boxes. My text boxes are aligned with the labels but in case of textareas, the labels are at the base of the textareas.  Please see the figure attached. The labels corresponding the textareas are aligned at lower line with the textareas.

How can I align my labels to be in the same line with the textareas or in the middle line of the textareas.

CSS and HTML code

```
<style>
    b {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
    }

    .upper-case {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .txtbox {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .txtarea {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .div_labels {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
</style>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Medical History :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaMedHistory" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="MEDICAL HISTORY" />
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Diagnosis :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaDiagnosis" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="DIAGNOSIS" />
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>ICD :</b>
<input type="text" id="inputTextICD" runat="server" class="upper-case txtbox" placeholder="ICD"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note, textarea elements aren't self-closing. Should be `<textarea></textarea>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addign vertical-align: top to b tag should do it.

And textareas arent self closing, added `</textarea>`

```css
    b {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    .upper-case {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .txtbox {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .txtarea {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .div_labels {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
    
    b {
      
    }
```

```html
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Medical History :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaMedHistory" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="MEDICAL HISTORY"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Diagnosis :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaDiagnosis" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="DIAGNOSIS" ></textarea>
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>ICD :</b>
<input type="text" id="inputTextICD" runat="server" class="upper-case txtbox" placeholder="ICD"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `display:flex;` to the div to make a flexbox and `margin:auto 0;` in `b` to make it aligned centrally vertical

```css
b {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 15%;
        margin:auto 0;
    }

    .upper-case {
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .txtbox {
        width: 300px;
    }

    .txtarea {
        width: 600px;
    }

    .div_labels {
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 13px;
        display:flex;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Medical History :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaMedHistory" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="MEDICAL HISTORY"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>Diagnosis :</b>
<textarea rows="4" runat="server" id="textareaDiagnosis" class="upper-case txtarea" placeholder="DIAGNOSIS" ></textarea>
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
</div>
<div class="div_labels">
<b>ICD :</b>
<input type="text" id="inputTextICD" runat="server" class="upper-case txtbox" placeholder="ICD"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add float:left; to the b tag style